# Appcelerator titanium - MapView on android causes app crash

Tags: android, maps, titanium, android-mapview, appcelerator

am trying to display a map on android emulator, using the following code:

```
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow();
window.open();
var mapView = Ti.Map.createView({
  mapType: Ti.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
  region:{
  latitude:33.74511, longitude:-84.38993,
  latitudeDelta:0.5, longitudeDelta:0.5
  },
  animate:true,
  regionFit:true,
  userLocation:true
});

window.add(mapView);
alert(mapView)//outputs Ti.Map.View
```

I have made all the steps mentioned here http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Maps+for+Android
but the application crashes. Does anyone has an idea what might be causing this?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without a stacktrace of your crash I can only guess it's caused by an emulator which does not provide the Google Maps API. See http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121105/crash-in-android-when-using-maps

Answer (score 0):

try removing the  your key here from the tiapp.xml file then refreshing the android emulator and it will work but resets to the empty google interface anybody got any ideas

Comment: is this an anwser of a question?

Answer (score 0):

You may have created other Map views elsewhere in your code.In that event,Google doesnt allow that and you end up with a force close (`IllegalStateException`)